# Invalid SQL data type while storing null value using prepared statement

Tags: java, android, ms-access, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I am using MS-Access as database.
In Ms access database I have one table with 2 columns, one is name and other one is document

For name i am using Text Data Type and For Document i am using OLE Object

if user not selecting any document then  i am trying to insert null value in OLE Object

```
prepardstmt.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.BLOB);
```

i am getting

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Invalid SQL data type
```

Exception

Can u please tell me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Your title says "null pointer exception" but you're showing an `SQLException`... which is it?

Comment: I all ready tried those but not working.. @gordThompson

Comment: I tried those DataTypes but still i am getting..java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Invalid SQL data type Expection @GordThompson

Comment: You tried `prepardstmt.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);`?

Answer (score 0):

to insert null value use `java.sql.Types.NULL`

refer [**javadocs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#NULL)

Comment: I tried this one but same java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Invalid SQL data type Expection i am getting...

Comment: Unfortunately, and despite what the Java documentation might say, that option won't work with the Microsoft Access Driver for ODBC and the JDBC-ODBC Bridge. See the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3018500/2144390) for more details.